# Check if the Intervals of a list are overlaped with the Intervals of another list

Tags: java, java-stream, jodatime, intervals

I have two lists with Intervals ie

`[2021-06-29T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-06-30T23:59:00.000+03:00, 2021-07-01T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-07-06T23:59:00.000+03:00]`

`[2021-06-25T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-06-30T23:59:59.000+03:00, 2021-07-01T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-07-06T23:59:59.000+03:00, 2021-07-06T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-07-11T23:59:59.000+03:00, 2021-07-11T00:00:00.000+03:00/2021-07-16T23:59:59.000+03:00....]`

I want to check whether the elements of the first one overlaps with the elements of the second or not. In case there isn't an overlap, I need to have a list with the intervals that they aren't overlaped with the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you'd want to go over the first list, and for each item go over the second list and check if any interval overlaps it. Streams make this a tad more elegant:

```java
List<Interval> list1 = // some intervals...
List<Interval> list2 = // some more internvals...
List<Interval> result = 
    list1.stream()
         .filter(i1 -> list2.stream().allMatch(i2 -> i1.overlap(i2) == null))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @DimitrisTsarouhas oops, my mistake. You should use `allMatch` instead of `anyMatch` and check if the overlap is equal to `null`. See my edited answer

Comment: I found it. It was noneMatch. Thanks!